# Facebook graph API explorer return empty list for /me/family

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook graph API explorer return empty list for /me/family.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAWGn.png)

I have given all the permissions while getting the access token.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your family members authorized your App, the list will be empty. For data privacy reasons, you can only get data of users who authorized your App.

Also, the `user_relationships` permission is deprecated-

Comment: Thanks. The real reason is that the 'user_relationships" permission is deprecated. This field will return empty. See: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/167234057298982/?disable_redirect=0

Comment: thanx, i have added the info to my answer